# Long server "Wait" time for non-ssl requests

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4

I have 3 websites on a VPS server. Suddenly about two days ago I found out one of them is frightfully slow. I tried to check them using [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com) tools and found the "Wait" time so long (about 6-10s).

Two of websites kassit.com & amraei.com are only accessible over HTTPS (http request will be redirected to https permanently, 301), and uxshiraz.org is only accessible over HTTP.

**Hypothesis #1:** script causes wait time
Test result: I put an empty PHP file on the server to test if the script is causing the issue and it was the same. Still long wait time.
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/chTXn7/http://uxshiraz.org/test.php

**Hypothesis #2:** SSL is causing waiting time
Test result: I checked both SSL websites, they had reasonable wait time.
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/b1P6sT/https://kassit.com/

**Hypothesis #3:** Redirection causes wait time
Test result: The website with no redirect also has a high wait time.
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/chTXn7/http://uxshiraz.org/test.php

**Other tested solutions:**

- Turned off HostnameLookups
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938682/how-to-reduce-server-wait-time
- When restart Apache, load time reduces for first request. 
  https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/eDln1k/http://uxshiraz.org/test.php
  Then it increases again in further requests.
  https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/ehXJLq/http://uxshiraz.org/test.php

So I concluded that high wait time is only for non-ssl version of website and probably related to Apache itself.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Apache 2.4.18

Comment: your scripts are making httpd crawl, that's for sure. SSL, or redirect will never be so slow. Better if you can check the actual status of threads with mod_status. Ideally move any third party modules such as (mod_php) out of the httpd server and use fcgi to invoke them. Use a threaded mpm and size the mpm according to your load, but you have given no info about your current setup other than version of the OS and the http server, so little else can be said aside from more generic recommendations.

Comment: The first cause of long waiting times is DNS resolution taking more time than wanted. At least one of the two domain has a warning related to its DNS configuration: http://dnsviz.net/d/kassit.com/WSYCvA/dnssec/

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You gave me helpful information. However, I migrated webserver from Apache to Nginx and waiting time dramatically decreased.

Comment: This does not exclude problems with DNS, it may just mean that Apache does more DNS resolution and hitting more problematic spots than nginx. In all cases, I advise you to correct your DNS warnings, as reported by above link.